# Proof reference for $1+2\mathbb Z_2\cong \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z_2$

Tags: reference-request, p-adic-number-theory

I'd appreciate a good clear reference for the proof of $1+2\mathbb Z_2\cong \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z_2$.

I've looked in *"P-adic Numbers: An Introduction"* by Gouvêa but couldn't find it.

**Update**:
Found the proof in Serres' *"A Course in arithmetic"* ch. 2 part 3 Prop. 8.

Answer (score 1):

$$1+4\Bbb{Z}_2= (1+4)^{\Bbb{Z}_2}$$

Proof :

- If $(a_n)\in \Bbb{Z}$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n$ converges in $\Bbb{Z}_2$ then $\lim_{n \to \infty} (1+4)^{a_n}$ converges in $1+4\Bbb{Z}_2$.
- For all $n$ then $(1+4)^{2^n}=\sum_{k=0}^{2^n} {2^n\choose k} 4^k \equiv 1+ 2^{n+2} \bmod 2^{n+3}$
- Given $b\in 1+4\Bbb{Z}_2$ by induction there exists $a_n\bmod 2^{n+1}$ such that $b \equiv (1+4)^{a_n} \bmod 2^{n+2}$ and hence $$b = \lim_{n \to \infty} (1+4)^{a_n} = (1+4)^{\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n}$$

Comment: How proving the statement in the first line proves what what I asked?

Comment: Please read all the answer

Comment: I did. Sorry, still don't get it..

Comment: Read it again. $b= (1+4)^a$ for some $a\in Z_2$, this is the group isomorphism $1+4Z_2,\times \to Z_2 ,+$

Comment: Maybe I didn't get the proof. I'll try going step by step: In the first line of the proof, why is it that $\lim_{n \to \infty} (1+4)^{a_n}$ converges __specifically__ in $1+4\Bbb{Z}_2$?

Comment: That it converges is proven just after. $1+4\Bbb{Z}_2$ is a group. Maybe you don't understand what is $\Bbb{Z}_2$, which kind of sequences converge and same for $1+4\Bbb{Z}_2$ ?

Comment: I do understand that. it's just that in the first line you talk about a general $a_n$ (which is a general power-2 series), then in the second line you refer to a specific $a_n=2^n$. But let say I did get it (which I didn't), I still can't see why this proves $1+2\mathbb Z_2\cong \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z_2$. Further, if you do have a suitable reference, so I won't trouble you, I'd much appreciate it.

Comment: I don't think you do. If $m$ is a positive integer $ \equiv 0 \bmod 2^n$ then $(1+4)^m \equiv 1 \bmod 2^{n+2}$ this proves if $(a_n)$ is Cauchy then $(1+4)^{a_n}$ is Cauchy. But you don't need it because I did construct a particular Cauchy sequence $(1+4)^{a_n}$ converging to $b$. Then $1+2Z_2= \pm 1 \times 1+4Z_2$ so the group structure reduces to that of $1+4Z_2$.

Comment: I think what is unclear to you is that it is the definition of $Z_2$ : the limits of sequences of integers that converge $\bmod 2^n$ for all $n$. The $2$-adic series are just particular cases of convergent sequences.

Comment: Ok, thanks for you're patience. That leaves the last sentence in your previous comment: "Then $1+2\mathbb Z_2=\pm1\times 1+4\mathbb Z_2$ so the group structure reduces to that of $1+4\mathbb Z_2$. Can you please clarify that? I still didn't get the connection to $1+2\mathbb Z_2$?

Comment: $1+2Z_2= \pm 1\ \ \times\ \ 1+4Z_2$ is a group isomorphism, once we know the structure of the RHS we know that of the LHS. Of course the point is that we found continuous isomorphisms and $Z_2$-modules isomorphisms.

Comment: But that's the isomorphism we wanted to prove.. How does knowing RHS structure assisted us in proving this isomorphism exists?

Comment: It is completely trivial that $1+2Z_2= \pm 1\ \ \times\ \ 1+4Z_2$ there is nothing to prove once you understand the definition of the ring $Z_2$ and its unit group $1+2 Z_2$. So what is $Z_2$ to you, which construction makes sense.